# Regular expression retrive the ID from JSON string. The 1st ID after occurnace of "State Code":

Tags: regex, json

I want a regex to match the " ID:1234 "

```
{
    {
   Id:"",

 "Address": {
            "Deleted": false,
            "Owner": 123,
            "PartyId": 123,
            "Modified": "11:41:29",
            "AddressType": "BILLING",
            **"StateCode":"Nw",**   
            **"Id": 1234,**
            "CountryCode": "US",
            "Version": 2,
            "AddressLine2": "",
            "OptimisticLock": 0
        },
        "PaymentMethodType": "CREDIT_CARD",
        "LastInvoiceDate": "12:18:00",
        "BillingDetailSet": [],
        "BillingCycleDate": "12:18:00",
        "Id": 15676
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably use JSON parser instead of a regex. Which language are you using?

Comment: Exactly what would you like to match/achieve? A regex matching exactly what you ask would be simply `/"Id": 1234/` but I suspect that's not what you want.

Comment: want to  get the Address ID

Comment: The ID which is present inside the Address attr or may be after State Code

Comment: Why do you have `{{` at the start ? It doesn't look like a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"StateCode":\s*"\w+",\s*"Id":\s*(\d+), this helped me

Answer (score 1):

Even while a regular expression is very probably not the best tool for the job, you can use this one :

```
"Address":\s*{[^}]*"Id":\s*(\d+),
```

For example in JavaScript you would do

```
var id = str.match(/"Address":\s*{[^}]*"Id":\s*(\d+),/);
```

It would be similar in other languages (in many languages you have to escape the `\` in the string literal).

Comment: It matches multiple IDs present

Comment: I want to retrive the Address ID

Comment: wow dude awesome but its matching all the String till ID, thankx for your help

Comment: "StateCode":\s*"\w+",\s*"Id":\s*(\d+), this helped me

Comment: Using "Address" as in my regex seems more reliable : it would still work if the order of the fields in the Address object changes.